# Scala: Create a new list where each element is the elemnt of old list repeated with different suffix

Tags: scala

This seems like it should be really easy but I can't quite put it together.  I want to take a list of strings and create a new list that contains two of each element form the first list but with a different suffix.  So:

```
List("a", "b", "c") -> List("a_x", "a_y", "b_x", "b_y", "c_x", "c_y"
```

I tried

```
val list2 = list1.map(i=> i+"_x", i+"_y")
```

but scala said I had too many arguments.  This got close:

```
 val list2 = list1.map(i=> (i+"_x", i+"_y"))
```

but it produced List(("a_x", "a_y"), ("b_x", "b_y"), ("c_x", "c_y")) which is not what I want.  I'm sure I ;m missing something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `flatMap`, to first map, then flatten the structure of the result into a flat list. Each individual result must itself be a collection (not a tuple):

```
scala> List("a", "b", "c").flatMap(i => List(i + "-x", i + "-y"))
res0: List[String] = List(a-x, a-y, b-x, b-y, c-x, c-y)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something silly that just escaping me.

Answer (score 6):

With a for comprehension:

```
scala> val prefixes = List("a", "b", "c")
prefixes: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val suffixes = List("x", "y")
suffixes: List[String] = List(x, y)

scala> for (prefix <- prefixes; suffix <- suffixes) yield prefix + "_" + suffix
res1: List[String] = List(a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c_x, c_y)
```

This is basically just syntactic sugar for Seth Tisue's answer.